# Can $f(x)$ and $f(1/x)^x$ be both completely monotone?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is non-constant and completely monotone with $f(0)=1$, that is
$$
(-1)^n f^{(n)}(x) \geq 0.
$$
Is it possible that $g(x):=f(1/x)^x$ is also completely monotone and non-constant?

Our conjecture based on numerics (Laplace transformations of discrete probability measures) is that this cannot be the case.
Indeed it seems that high derivatives of $g(x)$ always rapidly change signs for small values of $x$.
However, I can't seem to find a route towards a general argument.
In particular, trying to evaluate derivatives does not seem to be a very useful approach.

Any suggestions would therefore be more than welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Answer given before the precision « non constant » was given in the problem]

Yes, for example if for all $x \ge 0$, $f(x) = e^{-x}$, then for all $x>0$, $(f(1/x))^x = (e^{-1/x})^x = e^{-1}$.

Comment: Of course! I added the condition that $g(x)$ is also non-constant to the question now. Thanks for bringing up the example.

Comment: @Henrik You could probably adapt the answer to get $g$ non-constant. What about $e^{-x-1}$?

Comment: It doesn't seem unlikely, but the suggested one does not work as it does not fulfill $f(0)=1$.

Comment: Ok, here's a an example that fits all requirements: $e^{-\sqrt{x}}$. It is in fact invariant under the transformation and complete monotonicity is shown here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/340218/18467

Comment: Yes. It deserves to be given as an answer, not only a comment. $x \mapsto e^{-\sqrt{2x}}$ is the Laplace transform of the hitting time of 1 by a standard Brownian motion.